# Vue 3 on Ubuntu nginx shows blank page on refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, vue-router

I am trying to deploy a simple Vue 3 app using Vite (3.1.0), Pinia (2.0.22), TailwindCSS (3.1.8), and vue-router (4.1.5) on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu (22.04).

I deployed the build of the app to `/var/www/dist` and when I visit the ec2 instance it works as expected.

The problem occurs when I refresh the page or go directly to the URL of some of the routes specified.

**Scenario 1: - Root level**

Visting `http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/` will result in showing the homepage, as expected, and refresh will work as expected also.

**Scenario 2: - One level deep**

Visting `http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app` will result in showing the app dashboard, as expected, and refresh will work as expected also.

**Scenario 3: - Two levels deep**

Visting `http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/app/create` by clicking from the previous page will result in showing the create page, as expected, but when visiting this directly, or refreshing when on this URL, will result in a blank white page.

The console error is as follows:

```
index.c7b47a24.js:1 Failed to load module script: 
Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". 
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I have set up my nginx config file to handle SPA's using the try_files directive from guides for SPA's.

**Full Nginx Config:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/dist;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Vue router is set up using HTML5 mode using `createWebHistory()`:

```
export const getRouter = () => {
  if (router !== undefined) return router;
  router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
  });
...
```

So the problem seems to be at the second level of routes and onwards e.g `/foo/bar` that the problem is happening. I have hosted this same site on Vercel and it works as intended.

Thanks in advance.